# How to enable Matlab to listen real time data through C++ application

Tags: c++, matlab, real-time

I need to create a C++ add-in to Matlab where add-in will listen to packet coming from network and notify Matlab to draw an packet analysis graph. I understood that using a MEX file I can easily call c functions inside Matlab, but I could not find a way to notify Matlab when data is available at C++ end. Is there any way we can pass a user-defined Matlab function pointer into my C++ add-in?

BTW, I found this thread: [real-time-data-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504168/real-time-data-in-matlab)

Unfortunately suggestion is to use ActiveX control, but in my case, I need to create add-in in pure C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Gurobi](http://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Gurobi_Mex:_A_MATLAB_interface_for_Gurobi). It 'just' prints status information to the command window. Using a mex command like `mexCallMATLAB` you may access 'any' matlab function.

Answer (score 1):

Would it make your life easier if you could listen for the network data directly from Matlab?  I've never tried it, but there are a few submissions on MathWorks' File Exchange site that allow you to create sockets within Matlab.  Here's [a TCP/IP example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab) that creates both a client and a server, and here's a similar [UDP example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525).